# Applying View animation to Drawable directly instead of to the whole View

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-animation, android-drawable

I have an animation that I use to make an `ImageView` bounce when it is clicked.

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

and I apply it like this.

```java
view.startAnimation(
    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.bounce));
```

It works just fine, but the problem is that the animation affects not only the image drawn inside the `ImageView` but its background as well. When the animation occurs, its background enlarges and exceeds the view bounds, overlapping other views beside it. Is there a way to apply the animation only to the `Drawable` inside the `ImageView`, so that it does not affect the view background?

(P.S: If this question has already been answered, then please do mark it as a duplicate. I've searched but haven't been able to find an answer that matches what I am looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that can be done. But as a workaround, you can place one `ImageView` over another. Set the background to the `ImageView` below and set the background for the `ImageView` above as transparent. Now set the `Drawable` to the `ImageView` on top and animate that `ImageView`.